# ssh en maquina virtual

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

Mi sistema operativo es Ubuntu 18.04. Tengo instalado virtual box y dentro una maquina virtual con ubuntu server. Necesito tener acceso via ssh a la maquina virtual para lo cual probe lo que dice en este [post](https://jorgepuente.es/sistemas/acceder-una-maquina-virtual-virtualbox-traves-nat/). Sin embargo cuando escribo en mi terminal `ssh root@localhost -p 2222` me da el siguiente resultado

`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Intenté tambien con `ssh alejandro@localhost -p 2222` donde *alejandro* es el nombre del usuario root de la MV pero obtengo lo mismo. Agradezco cualquier ayuda o referencia de como lograr mi objetivo.

Comment: ¿cuáles son las ip de la máquina local y de la máquina virtual?

Comment: 1) Obtuviste algo con `ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` ? 2) Sabes si está corriendo tu servidor ssh? 3) Ya probaste sólo con la ip de la máquina virtual? Es decir, con el resultado de `hostname -I`? con `ssh root(o alejandro)@<ip de maquina virtual> -p 2222`?

Comment: Configuró SSH para usar el puerto 2222?  Normalmente es puerto 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedo sugerir agregar un segundo adaptador de red tipo "Solo anfitrión", esto lo que hace es crear una LAN virtual entre el servidor host y las máquinas virtuales.

Para agregar una red solo anfitrión, es necesario crearla primero a través de la interfaz de VirtualBox

[image: Agregar adaptador solo-anfitrión VirtualBox]

Luego agregarla a la máquina virtual

[image: Configurar adaptador 2 solo-anfitrión]

La máquina virtual tomará por defecto la IP 192.168.56.101